# What is the best way to store a google maps path (array of lattitude and longitudes)

Tags: sql, json

I am making a website where users can create routes on google maps and I  have been looking around for the best way to store a path (the coordinates of there root) from google maps. I have found a few different options and I am not sure which is the best.

Should I

Store them in a JSON file then just store the path of the json file in a sql column? The only problem with that is I then cant make querys based off the coordinates in the json file.

or

Store every single latitude and Longitude point in a separate row? The only problem I see with this is one path on google maps could have over 1000 different points which would take up a lot of space in the database.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the points seperate in a table like this

```
coordinates table
-----------------
track_id
lng
lat
sequence_number --> you should also store a sequence to know the order in which you want to connect the coordinates
```

and another table containing the track info

```
tracks table
------------
id
name
other_stuff
```

If you then want to get all points of a track called `My Bicycle Tour` then run

```
select c.lng, c.lat, c.sequence
from coordinates c
join tracks t on t.id = c.track_id
where t.name = 'My Bicycle Tour'
order by c.sequence
```

Remember a DB can easily hold millions and even billions of records and with proper indexes this is also very fast to query.

Comment: thats the only thing I was worried about, at what point does the db get "full"

Comment: The DB does not get full. Only if you do not have any more HD space left.

Comment: I mean is there a point where querys will start to slow down significantly and I should start storing data in a new DB?

Comment: No there is not really. Add indexes where you need them and you can query millions of records in milliseconds. At some point you can think about *Partitioning*. But maybe you will never get to this point.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! Will accept the answer as soon as I can.